# Bulk update with HibernateTemplate and IN clause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I would like to perform a database bulk update using Spring's `HibernateTemplate` (Hibernate 5.1).

HibernateTemplate offers the following interface: `public int bulkUpdate(String,Object...)`.

My query is `UPDATE entity item SET item.attribute.id = ? WHERE item.id in (?.....?)`.

I had a lot of troubles and want to ask **what is the proper way** to use HibernateTemplate

- The above query results in the deprecation warning `[DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 172 in HQ`
- Replacing the above query with JPA-style parameters (`UPDATE entity item SET item.attribute.id = ?1 WHERE item.id in (?2,?3.....?N)`) results in NullPointerException thrown by Hibernate when building parameter metadata
- As seen on [one of the most authoritative Hibernate sources](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/remember-that-ordinal-parameters-are-1-based-hibernatetemplate/), named parameters result in a misleading exception

Question is: how do I **properly** formulate a bulk update query using Spring's HibernateTemplate? As correctly reported by Mykong, HibernateTemplate automagically sets query parameters 0-based, but eventually the author got the program working with non-positional parameters without mentioning (or having at all) any warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the recommended way to do that now a days is with [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/). There is a getting started tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

So if you have an entity, you can add an interface that extends any of the reposiotry interfaces supported in SpringDataJpa and add a modifying query.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Customer c set c.firstName = ?1 where c.id = ?2")
    int updateNameById(String nameToUpdate, long id);
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Customer c set c.firstName = ?1 where c.id in (?2)")
    int updateNameByIds(String nameToUpdate, List<Long> ids);
}
```

Then Spring will implement that method and you can use the it as:

```
customerRepo.updateNameByIds("newName", Arrays.asList(cust.getId()));
```

This will generate the following sql:

```
update customer set first_name=? where id in (?)
```

[Here](https://github.com/evgdim/SpringDataJpaPlayground) is the project I used to test with

Comment: Thanks for pointing Spring JPA out. Unfortunately I am not sure we can implement this in our architecture soon (product I am working on is based on a company-maintained middleware that is shared across all developers). I will indeed discuss this with the team but now I need to find a solution. The query works with warnings at the moment so I am not blocked.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Probably you can get access to the entityManager / session and execute the update statement manualy.